# Sort Pivot by Grand Total - Tried with Find function

Tags: vba, sorting, pivot

I need to sort Grand Total in the pivot via VBA coding. I can do that with PT.pivotfields but its not giving me the option to sort by Grand Total.

Dim PC As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

```
Set PC = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Address)
    
    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A4").Select
    
    Set pt = PC.CreatePivotTable( _
    tabledestination:=ActiveCell, _
    TableName:="SegMentsPivot")

pt.AddFields "seg", "AgeBifur"

pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Case Id"), , xlCount
```

What should I do after this in order to sort Grand Total.

The second option that I tried with Find function, so first it reach to grand total and then sort, could not perform well.